# How to get unique values from Object Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

So I have an object array that as follows:

```
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
]
```

I want to filter data depending if the `name`, `amount` and `date` has duplicate.
This one doesn't filter even a duplicate name.

```
var unique = array.filter((v, i, a) =>{ return a.indexOf(v) === i});
```

How can I filter duplicate for this one based on `name`, `amount` and `date`?

Comment: it is not clear: once do you have 2 items that have equal `name` value but different `date` and `amt`. do you need to exclude them or not?

Comment: The most simple solution is to unique this array 3 times:
`array = _.uniqBy(array, 'name');

array = _.uniqBy(array, 'date');

array = _.uniqBy(array, 'amt');`

But it's not efficient

Comment: @skyboyer NO. only if the 3 values are duplicate.

Comment: @ramj then check by answer (second solution) `_.uniq(array);`, only you need lodash library

Comment: You should edit in the expected result since it is unclear what you mean by unique. The code you have shown filters out duplicate objects where all the keys and values are the same and is more accurately unique than what you are asking.

Comment: @Sylwester that's incorreect - the `indexOf` function when passed an object will only compare the object's _reference_ for an exact match within the array, and does not do a deep comparison on the keys or values therein.

Comment: @Alnitak You are correct. `===` does indeed only work on primitive types. I mixed objects in JS with arrays  in PHP.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this code it returns unique objects only.

```
var data = [
{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
{name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
{name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
{name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
]
var resArr = [];
data.filter(function(item){
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => (x.name == item.name && x.date == item.date && x.amt == item.amt));
  if(i <= -1){
        resArr.push(item);
  }
  return null;
});
console.log(resArr)
```

Do tell me if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this. Much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Your welcome sir.
If this was your desired solution then please mark it correct. :)

Comment: Sorry but this answer is just terrible. Why are you using `filter` if then you push the items in an array? Why are you returning null? Why function/var in 2018? There are a lot of functional way to achieve the result, and this is not one of them

Answer (score 19):

Just try this:

```js
     var array = [
        {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
        {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
        {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
        {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
        {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
        {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    ]

    var unique = Array.from(new Set(array.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse);
    
    console.log(unique)
```

Comment: Good Solution but it will only work when the objects are identical(all the values of objects are same).

Comment: Won't work if one of the elements in the array is `{amt:250,name:"Jupiter",date"2018-07-01"}` (i.e., same data in a different property order)

Comment: Terrible performance :)

Answer (score 10):

A solution with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
var data=[{name:"Joe",date:"2018-07-01",amt:250},{name:"Mars",date:"2018-07-01",amt:250},{name:"Joe",date:"2018-07-02",amt:250},{name:"Saturn",date:"2018-07-01",amt:250},{name:"Joe",date:"2018-07-02",amt:250},{name:"Jupiter",date:"2018-07-01",amt:250}];

var filtered = data.filter(function({name, date, amt}) {
    var key = `${name}${date}${amt}`;
    return !this.has(key) && this.add(key);
}, new Set);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: VERY elegant use of the callback thisarg

Comment: agree, very eloquent js  :)

Comment: Confusing.... RIP

Answer (score 5):

```js
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
]

let answer = [];

array.forEach(x => {
  if(!answer.some(y => JSON.stringify(y) === JSON.stringify(x))){
    answer.push(x)
  }
})

console.log(answer)
```

An alternative solution. You can use Array#forEach, Array#some, JSON.stringify to achieve what you want

Comment: Except if one of the elements in the array is `{amt:250,name:"Jupiter",date"2018-07-01"}` (i.e., same data in a different property order)

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://lodash.com/ library

If you need unique by only one value:

```
array = _.uniqWith(array, function(arrVal, othVal) {
    return arrVal.name == othVal.name || arrVal.date == othVal.date || arrVal.amt == othVal.amt;
}) 
console.log(array);
```

And if you need to remove unique by complete object:

```
array = _.uniq(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: @dark_gf What or where does `_.uniqWith` come from?

Comment: Yep it's a lodash library https://lodash.com/ . There is quite a lot of similar libs.
I've modified answer

Answer (score 3):

This code shows the duplicates in your console. If you want to print everything except the duplicates swap the `return true` with `return false` and the `return false` with `return true`.

```js
var orders = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
];

orders = orders.filter( (order, index) => {

  // iterate over the array to check for possible duplicates
  // iterating over the items we already checked isn't necessary so we start at index+1
  for( let i = index+1; i<orders.length; i++ ){
    if(
      orders[i].name === order.name
      && orders[i].date === order.date
      && orders[i].amt === order.amt
    ){
     // just logging this stuff so you can see what happens
     console.log( `${index} is a duplicate of ${i}` );
     // if a duplicate is found return true to the filter function
     return true; 
    }
  }
  // if no duplication is found return false to the filter function
  return false;
  
}); // end filter 

// log the result to the console
console.log(orders);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works by requiring by filtering the array such that the only elements included are those whose first matching entry in the original array (aliased as `a`) has the same `index` as the element currently being examined:

```
let uniq = array.filter(({name, date, amount}, index, a) =>
               a.findIndex(e => name === e.name &&
                                date === e.date &&
                              amount === e.amount) === index);
```

Comment: Just curious, have you got any references on how that object notation of your first parameter in the filter works?

Comment: @RMo it's called "destructuring" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Very nice. Just tested this and it seems to work well, as well as being the shortest and probably most efficient solution here.

Comment: What's an `e`? Everyone reading your answer could look it up on MDN but it's better to use real variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqWith):

```
import _ from 'lodash';

_.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual);
```

Outputs:

```
[
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your origin array:

```
var array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 }
];
```

You need a function to determine the criteria you want to check to make your object comparable with anothers.

**UPDATE**

Such a function could be an [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) that you should write to create a unique key to identify your objects and compare each other.

The proper hash function should return the same value if called with objects that have the same composed key.

In your case, when 2 objects have *name*, *date* and *amount* with the same value, the hash function is supposed to return the same value.

So you can directly compare hash values instead of objects.

In the case you asked for, all the values concurred to the filter, and here is a very trivial example of such a function, that is not proper an "hash" as the output is variable (should produce a **fixed** length value instead):

```
function objectHash (obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => {
        a += b;
        return a;
    }, '');
}
```

Now, you are now able to easily and properly compare items in your array in order to filter duplication.

```
var arrayMap = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    var hash = objectHash(item);
    if (typeof acc[hash] === 'undefined') {
        acc[hash] = Object.assign({}, item);
    }
    return acc;
}, {})
```

Then you have an object with unique key values, and to have back your unique array:

```
 var uniqueArray = Object.values(arrayMap);
```

Now you have your data.

Comment: A "hash" function can be expected to have collisions.   What you are describing is not a hash function, because you require uniqueness.

Comment: You're right it's not an "hash" function as an hash is a constant length output value calculated from a given variable length value in input. I used the word "hash" just to give an idea of a value that is calculated from the object.

Comment: Constant length is not a prerequisite for a hash either (and that isn't even true in your code where your so-called "hash" could be of variable length).  Please fix your answer, because as written it's very misleading.

Comment: What I wrote is a trivial example and a real hash algorithm is not necessary needed to achieve the result in this particular case. The point is that helps to understand the concept of a string unique representation of the object that helps in compare functions. And when I wrote "constant" I ment "fixed".

Comment: I don't object to the technique, I object to you calling it a hash because a true hashing algorithm is precisely *not* the right way to generate a unique key unless you've got an exceedingly collision tolerant algorithm (e.g. SHA-1 or better) but that would be overkill for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would have done it:

```js
const array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
];

function uniqueBy(arr, key, $some = false) {
  if (key instanceof Array) {
    if ($some) {
      return key.reduce(uniqueBy, arr);
    } else {
      const fnUnique = (obj) =>
        key.reduce((a, k) => `${a}-${obj[k]}`, '');
      return Object.values(arr.reduce((a, v) => {
          const key = fnUnique(v)
          return a[key] === undefined ? (a[key] = v, a) : a;
      }, {}));
  }
}
return Object.values(arr.reduce((a, v) => (a[v[key]] === undefined ? (a[v[key]] = v, a) : a), {}));
}

// print unique objects based on the given fields
console.log(uniqueBy(array, ['name', 'date', 'amt']));

// print unique objects based on any unique value in any given fields
console.log(uniqueBy(array, ['name', 'date', 'amt'], true));
```

This only cares about the given fields and thus you can get less results if you had objects that were duplicates but had other properties that were not interesting.

Passing `true` as the third argument treats the fields as unique themselves. Thus the result will only have objects where all the fields are unique and thus since the amount is the same you end up with one element.

Comment: But where's Mars, Saturn and Jupiter? My expected output is like this: `const array = [
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Mars", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },
    {name:"Saturn", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
    {name:"Jupiter", date:'2018-07-01', amt:250 },
]; 
Removing one `{name:"Joe", date:'2018-07-02', amt:250 },` since it's a duplicate entry.

Comment: @ramj They are gone because they had the same amount. I figured you wanted to remove the ones that had any of the columns duplictaed and thus the result would only have the ones with a unique name, a unique date and a unique value. I've added support for the one you wanted, but **you really should have added the expected result in your question**.

Answer (score 0):

Code to Filter unique id with name

```
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Jordan" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Bob" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "John" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Rhoda" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Harry" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Joe" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Jake" },
];
var unique = [];
var tempArr = [];
data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (unique.indexOf(value.name) === -1) {
        unique.push(value.name);
        tempArr.push(value.id);
    }
});
console.log('Unique Ids', tempArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and generic solution using typescript and building upon the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537887/930758) above. This returns an **array of unique objects of the same type as the original array, checking all properties, and should work for all types of objects**. It also works if the order of the properties is different in different items (in which case the JSON.stringify approach fails).

```
getDistinctObjectArray<T>(arr: T[]) {
    return arr.filter((item, ix, self) =>
      self.findIndex(f => 
        Object.keys(item).every(k => f[k] === item[k])) === ix);
  }
```

It works by filtering the array: for each item, it searches the array for the first occurrence of an item which has the same values for all its properties. If the index of the found item is not the same index as the current item, it is removed from the list.

Comment: Compared to the accepted answer, this has four function cycles instead of 3, so it means

O(n)+O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(n)^4

I also compared execution speed with the accepted answer, and it seems that this solution is five times slower:


const arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 1} ]
console.time("1")
const res2 = [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);

console.timeEnd("1")

console.time("2")
const res1 = arr.filter((item, ix, self) =>
      self.findIndex(f => 
        Object.keys(item).every(k => f[k] === item[k])) === ix);

console.timeEnd("2")

Comment: @dmytro.kushnir: Thanks for testing performance, I had not done that. However, the solution you compare against seems to be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55770305/930758), not the accepted answer. But that one has a big drawback: it opnly works if property order is the same for all items in the array, as I pointed out in my answer. In addition, VS code complains about using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse in this way.

Answer (score 0):

this my opinion , hope can help some one

```
const array =[{ "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "Thien" }, { "name": "Ngu" }, { "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "Thang" }, { "name": "An" }, { "name": "Den" }, { "name": "Den" }, { "name": "Sang" }, { "name": "Que" }, { "name": "Que" }, { "name": "Que" }, { "name": "Que" }, { "name": "Que" },]

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    const f = array[i]?.['name'] || null
    let flag = array[0]?.['name']
    let dub = null
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        const s = array[j]?.['name'] || null
        if (f === s || flag === s) {
            array.splice(j, 1)
            if (dub === s) {
                array.splice(j, 1)
            }
            dub = s
        } else {
            flag = array[j].name
        }

    }
}
console.log(array);
```

result:

```
[
  { name: 'Thang' },
  { name: 'Thien' },
  { name: 'Ngu' },
  { name: 'An' },
  { name: 'Den' },
  { name: 'Sang' },
  { name: 'Que' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with using a unique key. It outperforms Set+Json.Stringify/parse solution and any other deep search solutions since the search is taken by a specific key that should always exist in each array.

It also stores a unique value in [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in the following format: **[value, value-type]** to make sure it will be type independent.

```
function uniqueArrayOfObjects(objects, uniqueBy, keepFirst = true) {
  return Array.from(
    objects.reduce((map, e) => {
      const keyData = uniqueBy.map((key) => [e[key], typeof e[key]]).flat().join('-');
      if (keepFirst && map.has(keyData)) return map;
      return map.set(keyData, e);
    }, new Map()).values()
  );
}
```