# Delete duplicate in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to delete duplicate in array of objects but not as I found in stackoverflow questions,I want to check more than one property  and verify that is not duplicate,for example :

```js
 const input =  [
        {
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-acab-7b48c24ef2D0",
          "name": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "city": "Ukraine",
         
        },
        {
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-aBab-7b48c24ef2e0",
          "name": "Marcel",
          "lastName": "Pilate",
          "city": "Ukraine",
        },
        {
          "eventUid": "0fcc73d9-629f-4151-aBab-7b48c24ef2e0",
          "name": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "city": "Ukraine",
        }
      ]
```

Output shoukd be :

```js
const input =  [
        {
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-acab-7b48c24ef2D0",
          "name": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "city": "Ukraine",
         
        },
        {
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-aBab-7b48c24ef2e0",
          "name": "Marcel",
          "lastName": "Pilate",
          "city": "Ukraine",
        }
      ]
```

Because I want to check name,lastName and city for each element of the array, if there are duplicate then keep only the first.
Have you any idea how to check that ?

Comment: Not work for objects..

Comment: Are you saying `eventUid` is not the identifier?

Comment: The answer with the most upvotes in the linked question is just terrible

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina but [this one is elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547038/295783)

Comment: @alainber82 so the first found will be kept?

Comment: @mplungjan yes !

Comment: @mplungjan your solution is more elegant, and it works perfectly! thank you

Comment: @alainber82 Not mine, but yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.findLastIndex`.

The concept is that, while iterating the items, if the current index is equal to the last index then it exists twice, thus it can be removed.

Since you are comparing objects, and you want to check only 3 properties out of 4, you cannot use `lastIndexOf`. But instead you want to search the last index in the array with `findLastIndex`.

```
const filtered = 
  input.filter((item, index) => 
    input.findLastIndex(innerItem => 
        innerItem.name === item.name && 
        innerItem.lastName === item.lastName && 
        innerItem.city === item.city
    ) === index);
```

```js
const input = [{
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-acab-7b48c24ef2D0",
          "name": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "city": "Ukraine",
         
        },
        {
          "eventUid": "0fdb73d9-629f-4151-aBab-7b48c24ef2e0",
          "name": "Marcel",
          "lastName": "Pilate",
          "city": "Ukraine",
        },
        {
          "eventUid": "0fcc73d9-629f-4151-aBab-7b48c24ef2e0",
          "name": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "city": "Ukraine",
        }
      ];
      
const filtered = input.filter((item, index) => input.findLastIndex(innerItem => innerItem.name === item.name && innerItem.lastName === item.lastName && innerItem.city === item.city) === index)

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I think you meant to say that when the current index is NOT equal to the last index.

Comment: @0xRm Yes you're right, and when update with your idea it works!

Comment: It depends on if you want to keep the first or the last match. Usually it doesn't matter, but in this case it matters since they have different eventUids